# How could I filter certain logs using log4j properties file?

Tags: java, logging, web-scraping

I'm scraping a website and trying to log all the activity using log4j. I'm pretty new to log4j so I have done some research on my own (that's why I might have missed something).

First of all this is my properties file:

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootLogger = INFO,CONSOLE, FILE

# Define the console appender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] - %m %n

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=C:/Users/Ivan/Desktop/log.out
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] - %m %n
```

On the other hand, I've done something like:

```
for(Product oneProduct : products){         
    slf4jLogger.info("Processing Prices: " + oneProduct.getName());
    //MORE STUFF
}
```

However I'm getting messages like (besides the one that I want):

2016-02-17 00:25:54,781 [pool-2-thread-6] - Bad input type: "mail", creating a text input

And it's pretty anoying to read it on the console besides and the output file. As far as I see, it's possible to use filters within the properties file but I haven't got any luck so far. Any ideas? Please let me know if I wasn't clear enough. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the line where you create `slf4jLogger`?
Also the list of JARs you include on your classpath.

Comment: Of course, here is where I create a sfl4Logger: private static final
Logger slf4jLogger = Logger.getLogger(CasaDelAudio.class);